# UIimageView rotate around a center point of another UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two images.
One image is rectangle
second is triangle
i want to rotate tringle image from the center point of rectangle image using one finger or touch event.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zilY.png]

Comment: If you have got solution for this then please post answer. I have same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that i have to use `[view.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)]` 
and it solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the math for this will get decently complex if you wish for the image to rotate in a circle of any size around the rectangles center point, but a good start would be to define the anchor point of the triangle image view, e.x.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)


[[triangleImageView layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake:(0.5,0.0)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [triangleImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90))];
}];
```

Comment: i have tried it but didn't get any success.can you please give me sample code.
Thanks for positive reply :)

Comment: @user1627721 You'll have to be significantly more specific than that.

Comment: CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([view bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([view bounds]));
 CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
 CGPoint previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:view];
  [view.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.25, 0.0)];
            CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform,angleInRadians*M_PI_4/2);
            view.transform = transform;